# TYPO3 Core Security Update from 9.5.28 to 9.5.29 breaks email links from CKeditor. Href removed from A-Tag

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, xss, typo3-9.x

E-Mail link in frontend from Ckeditor in TYPO3 Core 9.5.28:

```
<p><a href="javascript:linkTo_UnCryptMailto(%27rfnqyt%5C%2FyjxyEyjxy3ij%27);">E-Mail Link</a></p>
```

E-Mail link in frontend from Ckeditor in TYPO3 Core 9.5.29:

```
<p><a>E-Mail Link</a></p>
```

**The href-attribut is completly removed from the a-tag.**

Render-Defintion in my Fluid-Template:

```
<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc">{bodytext}</f:format.html>
```

I think the problem results from the following changes: https://github.com/typo3/typo3/commit/ac8f1fc3ac

- Can anyone confirm the erratic behavior?
- Do I need to change anything in my fluid template?

Currently I have downgraded the project back to 9.5.28. Here everything works as it should.

Probably the 10 version is also affected. So far not checked by me yet.

Comment: See https://forge.typo3.org/issues/94776 which was already fixed, a release will be published soon.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/TYPO3/html-sanitizer/issues/23 with details and fixes.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful information and links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've compiled an overview of current topics related to HTML sanitization in recent TYPO3 version 11.3.2, 10.4.19 and 9.5.29.

→ see https://github.com/TYPO3/html-sanitizer/issues/23

Besides that, I like to encourage folks to create bugs reports at forge.typo3.org instead of posting them on StackOverflow. Thanks!

---

***Update Aug 16th, 2021*** 
New TYPO3 versions have been released addressing this topic, please see https://typo3.org/article/typo3-10420-9530-and-1133-maintenance-releases-published for details and a *change per version matrix* attached to it

Comment: You are right. forge.typo3.org would have been a better place for my bug report. Thanks for you reply.

Comment: I deleted my bad typoscript solution. I think that's the better way to protect other people from "doing wrong things"... :-)

Comment: That‘s better. Thanks! ❤️